# IIS not running on windows7

Tags: iis, windows-7

I'm having a problem with IIS on Windows 7. When I try to access `http://localhost`, I am getting a "page can not be displayed" error.

Please tell me what I need to do to run IIS. I'm using IIS default that comes with Windows 7.

Comment: Did you start the service?

Comment: Note that IIS does not exist on Windows Home Edition.

Answer (score 3):

IIS doesn't get installed as default on Windows 7.  You need to go into add/remove features and add it.

Comment: This is correct. Note that if you're running the Home edition, IIS is not included. You might try [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb) instead.